# Does Kubernetes have the ability to spin up new nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

Does Kubernetes have the ability/need to hook into a cloud provider (AWS, Rackspace) to spin up new nodes? If so, how does it then provision the node - does it run Ansible etc? Or will Kubernetes need to have all the nodes available to it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is explained in the following blog posting that describes the new [kubeadm](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) command:

http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/09/how-we-made-kubernetes-easy-to-install.html

> There are three stages in setting up a Kubernetes cluster, and we
>   decided to focus on the second two (to begin with):
>
> 1. Provisioning: getting some machines
> 2. Bootstrapping: installing Kubernetes on them and configuring certificates
> 3. Add-ons: installing necessary cluster add-ons like DNS and monitoring  services, a pod network, etc
>
> We realized early on that there's enormous variety in the way that
>   users want to provision their machines.
>
> They use lots of different cloud providers, private clouds, bare
>   metal, or even Raspberry Pi's, and almost always have their own
>   preferred tools for automating provisioning machines: Terraform or
>   CloudFormation, Chef, Puppet or Ansible, or even PXE booting bare
>   metal. **So we made an important decision: kubeadm would not provision
>   machines.** Instead, the only assumption it makes is that the user has
>   some computers running Linux.

---

Update

- http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/01/stronger-foundation-for-creating-and-managing-kubernetes-clusters.html

Comment: kubeadm is like minikube, it's not production grade at all.

ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

Comment: @Hang Agreed. The question referred to whether provisioning infrastructure was part of Kubernetes or not. The purpose of quoting the kubeadm documentation is that it expresses the opinion and priorities of the SIG-cluster-lifecycle special interest group.